# IntelliJIdea front-end plugin with JLink

Tags: java

I did some proof-of-concept work on having Mathematica Front-End (MathSessionPane) in the IntelliJ Idea as a plugin https://github.com/dubrousky/Mathematica-REPL. It uses JLink as a runtime dependency and is available as plugin. Does it make sense to include it somehow into the existing Mathematica Support plugin (https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin) or keep it separate? Can it be considered as a duplication of Workbench functionality that is prohibited by WRI licence?

[image: Plugin Snapshot]

Comment: This question is off topic here, but your plugin does look very interesting.  Why don't you contact @halirutan (the Mma Support plugin's author) and also join [the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8636/intellijidea-plugin-for-mathematica)?  This is something you should ask him.  The main site is not suitable for arbitrary discussions, but the chatroom I linked is.  Just please remember, by closing this question I'm simply guiding you to the correct discussion forum (chatroom), not making a statement on your plugin, which I'm very interested in.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a practical, answerable question about Mathematica.

Comment: Some of us (@rm) use PyCharm and the console therein to have a simple Mathematica session inside IDEA. Funny enough, I was having the same idea as you did yesterday night (check the [chat log](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18893944#18893944)). There remain some things to discuss, as for example such a console would steal one of your two possible Mathematica kernels and it should be very safe in case the kernel you use crashes. It would be very bad if dead kernels are around that occupy licences.

Comment: I do not have required reputation score to write into the chat room. As for idea - I had it half a year ago after installed your plugin but was unfamiliar with the plugin development at the time.

Comment: @dubroua try again.

Comment: Tried again - it worked. Thanks.